# reactjs - onClick login & close modal?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to be able to click "Login" and have it close the modal but I don't understand how I would reach that.  Here's my login.js -

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Login extends Component {

    render() {
        const { errorMessage } = this.props

        return (
            <div>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Login</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <input type='text' ref='username' className="form-control" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} placeholder='Username'/>
                    <input type='password' ref='password' className="form-control" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} placeholder='Password'/>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)} className="btn btn-primary">
                        Login
                    </Button>
                    {errorMessage &&
                    <p style={{color:'red'}}>{errorMessage}</p>
                    }
                </Modal.Footer>
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        const username = this.refs.username
        const password = this.refs.password
        const creds = { username: username.value.trim(), password: password.value.trim() }
        this.props.onLoginClick(creds)
    }
}

Login.propTypes = {
    onLoginClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    errorMessage: PropTypes.string
}
```

navbar.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Button, MenuItem, Modal, Nav, NavDropdown, Navbar, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { IndexLinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import Login from '../Login/Login';
import Logout from '../Logout/Logout';
import { loginUser, logoutUser } from '../../actions/actions'
import './Navigation.css'

const Navigation = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return { showModal: false };
    },

    close() {
        this.setState({ showModal: false });
    },

    open() {
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
    },

    render() {

        const { dispatch, isAuthenticated, errorMessage } = this.props;


        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <IndexLinkContainer to="/"><a href="/">myApp</a></IndexLinkContainer>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle />
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Collapse>
                        <Nav pullRight>
                            {!isAuthenticated &&
                                                            <NavItem
                                onClick={this.open}
                            >
                                Login
                            </NavItem>
                            }
                            {isAuthenticated &&
                            <NavDropdown title="Welcome">
                                <MenuItem>
                                    <Logout
                                        onLogoutClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())}
                                    />
                                </MenuItem>
                            </NavDropdown>
                            }
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
                <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
                                <Login
                                    errorMessage={errorMessage}
                                    onLoginClick={ creds => dispatch(loginUser(creds)) }
                                />
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }

})

Navigation.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    errorMessage: PropTypes.string,
    showModal: PropTypes.bool
}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: If you don't have control over the parent component - then you can have your component return `undefined`, and if a prop indicating `logged in` is true. If you have parent control, then have that render `undefined`, that would be more true to react lifecyle, as then `componentDidMount` etc will trigger.

Comment: I have control over the parent I'll include the respective code from the navbar.